# How to use conditions inside a Makefile define function

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to reduce the number of function calls by having a single function with conditions inside, but my code doesn't work without showing any errors.

```
define say
    $(if $(filter hi,  $(1)), $(echo "Hello   ${2}"))
    $(if $(filter bye, $(1)), $(echo "Goodbye ${2}"))
endef

.SILENT:

test:
    $(call say, hi, "John Smith")
```

Besides, I initially used an ifeq/else structure, but I received syntax errors. I also noticed that I cannot declare variables in this scope.

```
define say
    ifeq ($(1), hi)
        echo "Hello ${2}"
    else ifeq ($(1), bye)
        echo "Goodbye ${2}"
    endif
endef

.SILENT:

test:
    $(call say, hi, "John Smith")
```

---

I also tried another approach to solve the same problem:

```
HI  = "Hello"
BYE = "Goodbye"

define say
    echo "${${1}} ${2}"
endef

.SILENT:

test:
    $(call say, HI, "John Smith")
```

But this one doesn't work either, mainly because the variable-variable (`$($(1))`) doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, why are you adding `.SILENT:` to your makefiles?  You should never do that at least until the makefile is working.  Adding `.SILENT:` then trying to understand why your makefile doesn't work is like running your program with its output sent to `/dev/null` and trying to understand what's wrong with it.

All of your issues are related to not having a clear distinction in your mind between makefiles, which use makefile syntax, and recipes, which are shell scripts and use shell script syntax.

A makefile is a combination of two different languages.  All commands in recipes are expanded and sent to the shell.  All commands outside of recipes are makefile commands.  You can't use makefile commands (like `ifeq` etc.) in a shell script.  And you can't use shell commands (like `$(echo ...)`) in the makefile (outside of a recipe).

When you want to use the `$` in a shell script, you have to escape it as `$$` in the makefile recipe so that it won't be interpreted as a make macro.

So, given that:

```
define say
    $(if $(filter hi,  $(1)), $(echo "Hello   ${2}"))
    $(if $(filter bye, $(1)), $(echo "Goodbye ${2}"))
endef
```

This would work, except you use `$(echo ...)` which is interpreted by make as a make variable with a really weird name.  Make will look it up, see it's not defined, and expand to nothing.  You can do this:

```
define say
    $(if $(filter hi,  $(1)), echo "Hello   ${2}")
    $(if $(filter bye, $(1)), echo "Goodbye ${2}")
endef
```

This will expand to and `echo` command, which will then be passed to the shell (because you called it from within a recipe), and the shell will run it.

For this one:

```
define say
    ifeq ($(1), hi)
        echo "Hello ${2}"
    else ifeq ($(1), bye)
        echo "Goodbye ${2}"
    endif
endef
```

this can't work because you invoke it from within a recipe and, as we've mentioned above, `ifeq` is not a shell command and so the shell won't recognize it.  `call` does NOT "run" a set of make commands.  `call` expands a string, with some extra variables in-scope for the arguments.

For this one:

```
define say
    echo "${${1}} ${2}"
endef
```

This one is due to a bug in GNU make.  Generally the rule is that preceding whitespace is ignored and trailing whitespace is not ignored.  Unfortunately it seems that the `call` function doesn't do this correctly for arguments, so when you write:

```
$(call say, HI, "John Smith")
```

the first argument has the value  `HI` (including the space).  So make tries to expand the variable `${ HI}` and that, of course, is not a valid variable name.  If you remove the whitespace it will work:

```
$(call say,HI,"John Smith")
```

I also have to point out that all this quoting is totally unnecessary.  make doesn't care about quotes at all; they're just another character to it, like `a` or `b`.  These quotes will be passed verbatim to the shell.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. Yes, this was my very first time diving into a Makefile! :D by try & error, I kinda learned your point, but I understood it better with your explanation.

Comment: I added `.SILENT:` since the system printed out all commands before their results, but having this target, I only see what I print out myself and even the Make errors are there. And For strings wrapped in double-quotes, I guess I'll keep them like that for better readability in my IDE, as they are proved to be harmless so far :D

Comment: Yes, but reading the commands will help you understand what the makefile is doing and figure out why it's not doing what you want.  That's exactly why you shouldn't use `.SILENT:` if your makefile is not working.  As for the quotes, they may cause problems in the future but as long as you only ever use them in situations where the shell will remove them for you it won't cause a problem.

Comment: Noted, Thanks! Regarding the quotation marks, just for future viewers, I need to add that strings should only be wrapped once not twice. So if I have a variable up there that already wraps my text, I will echo that variable as is, without wrapping it again (or vice-versa), with the exception of what's being sent by call.